# Kendo TreeView Filter

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-ui

Can kendo treeview be filtered based on parent Node text?? I have a treeview with user name as parent node and user details as child nodes. I need to perform a search based on User name.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

No built-in or easy way to do this. The treeview is composed of multiple dataSources for each branch. So you need o recursively iterate through all the [children](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/node#fields-children) dataSources and use their filter method.